# Filtering RDD and List in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with following structure

```
         RDD[((String), List[(Int,String)])]
```

And it contain this data

```
        ((John),List((4,00A), (5,00A), (15,00B), (15,00C)))
        ((Billing),List((7,00A)))
        ((Root),List((1,00A), (2,00B), (3,00C)))
        ((Marsh),List((2,00B), (3,00C)))
```

Now i want to filter it by following rules

1 : If list does not contain '00A' then do not return it

2 : If list contain '00A' then return all '00A' items and also '00C' items in the list. So result should look like this.

```
      ((John),List((4,00A), (5,00A), (15,00C)))
      ((Billing),List((7,00A)))
      ((Root),List((1,00A), (3,00C)))
```

> EDIT: Adding code posted in comment.

I have tried this:

```
val rdd = df
  .rdd
  .map{case Row(id: Int, name: String, code: String) => ((name), List((id, code)))}
  .reduceByKey(_ ++ _); 

val r = rdd
  .map{case (t, list) => { 
          val tempList = list.map{case (id, code) => (id, code)} 
          val newList = tempList.map{case (id, "00A") => (id, "00A")
                                     case (id, "00C") => (id, "00C")
                                     case (id, code) => List.empty } 

          (t, newList)}
   };
```

Comment: I have tried this

val rdd = df.rdd.map { case Row(id: Int, name: String, code: String) => ((name), List((id, code))) }.reduceByKey(_ ++ _);

    val r = rdd.map({
      case (t, list) => {
        val tempList = list.map({
          case (id, code) => (id, code)
        })

        val newList = tempList.map({
          case (id, "00A") => {
            (id, "00A")
          }
          case (id, "00C") => {
            (id, "00C")
          }
          case (id, code) => {
            List.empty
          }
        })

        (t, newList)
      }
    });

Comment: Your example data doesn't make sense. What is `(John)`? Please provide a correctly-Scala-formatted version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward

It's not really an RDD/Spark question so I've done it with Lists. If you were using lists, you could do the `filter`/`map` as one `collect` but `collect` means something quite different for RDD

Assuming your data was really meant to look like this:

```
 val xs = List(("John",List((4,"00A"), (5,"00A"), (15,"00B"), (15,"00C"))),
            ("Billing",List((7,"00A"))),
            ("Root",List((1,"00A"), (2,"00B"), (3,"00C"))),
            ("Marsh", List((2,"00B"), (3,"00C"))))
```

Then first we filter to get only the records with "00A" somewhere.

```
 val filtered = xs.filter{case (key, ys) =>ys.exists(y=>y._2 == "00A")}
```

Them map over tte result to return only the "00A" and "00C" ones

```
 val result = filtered.map{case (key, ys) => 
                             (key, ys.filter(y=>y._2 == "00A" || y._2 == "00C"))}
 //> result  : List[(String, List[(Int, String)])] = List(
 // (John,List((4,00A), (5, 00A), (15,00C))),
 // (Billing,List((7,00A))), 
 // (Root,List((1,00A), (3,00C))))
```

Comment: thanx @The Archetypal Paul. I am exactly looking for that.